# Python 2.7.11 on OSX 10.11.3 gives Segmentation fault: 11 with package gspread

Tags: macos, python-2.7, segmentation-fault, gspread

I'm using the package [`gspread`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) to interact with google spreadsheets on python 2.7 and OSX 10.11, and I get segmentation fault: 11. However, I'm able to download the google spreadsheet content despite this error showing up.

Here's an example of the error.

```
bash-3.2$ ipython
fPython 2.7.11 (default, Dec 26 2015, 17:47:53) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from etl.spread import gspread, credentials

In [2]: gs = gspread.authorize(credentials)

In [3]: 
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? y
Segmentation fault: 11
```

*It takes several seconds between typing y to exit, and actually exiting. I'm not sure if that indicates something*

Here's the [full crash report](http://pastebin.com/14CrZBYb)

Comment: no responses huh? The same happened to me. osx-10.11.6. all solutions say its the python version for an earlier version of python. No solutions work